# Pass a variable into a for range loop and then grow the value?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, range

In Turtle graphics I'm trying to create a series of boxes, one within the next. My main question is how does one pass values into a for i in range(4): loop and have the values increase or decrease by a value? Here, I've created two boxes but I'd like to make the second smaller and fit in the first?

```html
import turtle as t
def block(x, y, length, scale):
    for i in range(2):
        t.up()
        t.goto(x,y)
        t.down()
        for i in range(4):
            t.forward(length * scale)
            t.right(90)
block(100, 100, 100, 1)
t.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your starting x and y coordinates and side length variables, change them every time through the loop, and move the turtle every time. Something like this:

```
import turtle as t
x = 100
y = 100
side = 100
decrease = 10
num_rect = 2
for i in range (num_rect):
    t.up()
    t.goto(x, y)
    t.down()
    for i in range(4):
            t.forward(side)
            t.right(90)
    x += decrease / 2
    y -= decrease / 2
    side -= decrease
t.mainloop()
```